# method signature with extended generics types "incorrect"

Tags: java, generics

I get a compile time error with java generics that I don't understand.

I have two methods:

```
public static final <T> T doStuff(List<T> list, int k, Comparator<T> comparator) {
  T element = null;
  //some stuff done
  return element;
}

public static final <T extends Comparable> T doStuff(List<T> list, int k) {
  Comparator<T> comparator = new Comparator<T>() {
    public int compare (T o1, T o2) {
      return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
  };
  return doStuff(list, k, comparator);
}
```

This fails with method doStuff(java.util.List, int, java.util.Comparator) not found.
When I change the second method to:

```
public static final <T> T doStuff(List<T> list, int k) {
  Comparator<T> comparator = new Comparator<T>() {
    public int compare (T o1, T o2) {
      return ((Comparable)o1).compareTo(o2);
    }
  };
  return doStuff(list, k, comparator);
}
```

It works fine.

Can someone please shed some light on this.

Comment: The code above compiles as is.. you only get a compiler warning (with the -Xlint option) about the user of the raw type `Comparator`.

Answer (score 2):

Your generic parameter is bounded by the *raw* type `Comparable`, which is *not* comparable to itself (ie `T`).

Instead, change the type from `<T extends Comparable>` to `<T extends Comparable<T>>`.

---

The following code compiles:

```
public static final <T> T doStuff(List<T> list, int k,
        Comparator<T> comparator) {
    T element = null;
    // some stuff done
    return element;
}

public static final <T extends Comparable<T>> T doStuff(List<T> list, int k) {
    Comparator<T> comparator = new Comparator<T>() {
        public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    };
    return doStuff(list, k, comparator);
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't over here. I am using JDK 1.5.0_22.

Comment: Did you copy-paste my code to your IDE? It should compile even with 1.5

Comment: Yes, I get Error: method doStuff(java.util.List<T>, int, java.util.Comparator<T>) not found in class...

Comment: for best results use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Answer (score 1):

Comparable is in itself a generic. What happens if you change to

```
public static final <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T doStuff(List<T> list, int k) ...
```

?

Comment: Error(1113,10): method doStuff(java.util.List<T>, int, java.util.Comparator<T>) not found in class...